# How to replace "webpack-internal" in error stack output?

Tags: javascript, logging, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to properly do error logging. I'm using Vue framework (webpack starter).

When I do `console.log(error.stack)` I get in browser dev console:

```
Error: offline
    at Socket.eval (socket.service.js?19d1:20)
    at Socket.onack (socket.js?0183:311)
    ...
```

When I do `sendErrorStackToServer(error.stack)` or `someDiv.innerText = error.stack` I get:

```
Error: offline
    at Socket.eval (webpack-internal:///92:48:83)
    at Socket.onack (webpack-internal:///101:311:9)
    ...
```

How to replace **webpack-internal** with something more descriptive (like in the first case)?